# A Statistical Estimate for the number of times you can divide an even by 2 until it becomes odd

Tags: statistics, estimation

I was wondering if exists function **n(m)** (where m is an even number) that can give an unbiased estimate for the number of divisions by 2 for even number **m** until it becomes odd

Comment: You'll need to say what distribution on the even numbers you are thinking of.  Of course, a crude observation is that  (in some reasonable sense) half of them are divisible by $2$ but not by $4$, then half of the multiples of $4$ are not divisible by $8$ and so on.  That leads to an expectation that two divisions suffices.  Perhaps that is good enough for your purposes.

Comment: @Lulu I thought of the same thing but to me, it looks like a very trivial estimate.  is not there a more complex estimate ?

Comment: Again, without specifying which distribution you have in mind, nor what test you'd like it to pass, it is hard to say anything more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a finite sequence of even numbers, all of them will be divisible by 2 once, 1/2 of them will be divisible by 2 twice, 1/4 will be divisible by 2 thrice, 1/8 will be divisible by 2 four times, etc, so you could use the constant function:

$$n(m) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{32} + \frac{1}{64} + ... = 2$$

If you want an *upper* bound for the number of divisions by 2, then

$$n(m) = \log_2 m$$

Comment: How did you derive the upper bound?

Comment: Please respect [the guidelines for enforcing quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Thank you.